# Golang net/http fileserver giving 404 on any pattern other than "/"

Tags: http, go, http-status-code-404, handler

Hello awesome stackoverflow community,

Apologies for the lame question.
I've been playing around with the net/http package in Go, and was trying to set an `http.Handle` to serve the contents of a directory. My code to the Handle is

```
 func main() {
     http.Handle("/pwd", http.FileServer(http.Dir(".")))
     http.HandleFunc("/dog", dogpic)
     err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
     if err != nil {
         panic(err)
     }
 }
```

My dogpic handler is using `os.Open` and an `http.ServeContent`, which is working fine.

However, when I try to browse `localhost:8080/pwd` I am getting a 404 page not found, but when I change the pattern to route to `/`, as

```
http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(".")))
```

it is showing the contents of the current page. Can someone please help me figure out why the `fileserver` is not working with other patterns but only `/`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `http.FileServer` as called with your `/pwd` handler will take a request for `/pwdmyfile` and will use the URI path to build the filename. This means that it will look for `pwdmyfile` in the local directory.

I suspect you only want `pwd` as a prefix on the URI, not in the filenames themselves.

There's an example for how to do this in the [http.FileServer](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer) doc:

```
// To serve a directory on disk (/tmp) under an alternate URL
// path (/tmpfiles/), use StripPrefix to modify the request
// URL's path before the FileServer sees it:
http.Handle("/tmpfiles/", http.StripPrefix("/tmpfiles/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/tmp"))))
```

You'll want to do something similar:

```
http.Handle("/pwd", http.StripPrefix("/pwd", http.FileServer(http.Dir("."))))
```

Comment: Also the built-in mux will use exact matches by default. It's only a prefix (directory) match if the path ends in a slash. So `http.Handle("/pwd"...` will match *only the exact path* `/pwd`, while `http.Handle("/pwd/"...` will match anything beginning with `/pwd/`, [per the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux).

Comment: God bless you!!

Answer (score 1):

you should write `http.Handle("/pwd", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./")))`

http.Dir references a system directory.

if you want localhost/ then use `http.Handle("/pwd", http.StripPrefix("/pwd", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./pwd"))))`

it will serve all you have into /pwd directory at localhost/